# Accessing siblings elements in a v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

New to Vuejs 2, need a bit of help to understand how this would be done.

So, I have a template that looks like the following:

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item" v-for="item in items">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="title">{{ item.title }}</div>
                <div class="action">
                    <a href="#" @click.prevent="editSettings(item, $event)">
                        Click Me
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div v-if="showSettings" class="settings">
                <!-- Settings component for this item. -->
                <settings-panel item="item"></settings-panel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The scripts looks like this:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                // This data is from an API usually and only
                // shown here for example purposes
                { id: 1, title: 'Title 1' },
                { id: 2, title: 'Title 2' },
                { id: 3, title: 'Title 3' },
                { id: 4, title: 'Title 4' }
            ],
            showSettings: false
        };
    },
    methods: {
        editSettings(item, event) {
            // Only show the clicked items settings, not all
            this.showSettings = !showSettings;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the easiest and cleanest approach to only showing the settings panel for the clicked item?  Right now, if I click the `Click Me` settings, all settings open up. The `data` listed in the code is only there for example, but is coming from an API so I don't have much to do with the manipulation of that data.

Can anyone help lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `showSettings` add a `selectedItem`.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                // This data is from an API usually and only
                // shown here for example purposes
                { id: 1, title: 'Title 1' },
                { id: 2, title: 'Title 2' },
                { id: 3, title: 'Title 3' },
                { id: 4, title: 'Title 4' }
            ],
            selectedItem: null
        };
    },
    methods:{
      selectItem(item){
        if (this.selectedItem === item) this.selectedItem = null
        else this.selectedItem = item
      }  
    }
}
```

And modify your template to set the `selectedItem` when the item is clicked and show the settings only if the `selectedItem` is the current item.

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item" v-for="item in items">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="title">{{ item.title }}</div>
                <div class="action">
                    <a href="#" @click.prevent="selectItem(item)">
                        Click Me
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div v-if="selectedItem === item" class="settings">
                <!-- Settings component for this item. -->
                <settings-panel item="item"></settings-panel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The above will show the settings for the clicked item if the currently selected item is not the item that was clicked. If the currently selected item *is* the one that was clicked, it will hide the settings.

Comment: FAST ANSWER!  Thanks!  I need it to toggle, but this lead me in the right direction for completion!

Comment: @Sean Updated to toggle. There are a number of ways to do this. This is quick and easy.

Comment: lets say that I have a Post component for individual posts and a Posts component that will generate many Post with v-for; is there a way to access the post siblings and when one is clicked to hide others posts "settings" ? (a node in that component), something like a vuetify expand or classic accordion..

Comment: @user348078 sure. I'd probably still let the Posts component set the state, but you could emit the selected Post from the Post's themselves to the Posts component and then set some property (visible, selected, whatever) when the post is equal to the selected post.

Comment: Hmm but in my Posts all I have is <post v-for="post in posts" >. So how can I set wich post to have its v-card ( settings ) visible? By passing a prop with current selected post?